# How to solve the OOM problem encountered when using dgl to process ultra large image data？

Tags: deep-learning, lazy-loading, dataloader, dgl, gnn

I am trying to generate mini batch data using a sampler with built-in support in DataLoader to support random batch training on large images,
`dgl.dataloading.DataLoader( graph, valid_nids, sampler, batch_size=1024, shuffle=False, drop_last=False, num_workers=0, device=device )`
I found that this class takes the graph object as the first parameter, but due to the large amount of node and edge data, I encountered an OOM problem when using the following method to build the graph.
`graph = dgl.graph((u, v))`

My dataset has about 40 million nodes, plus about 200GB of feature information. I don't have a distributed environment and a single machine has 60GB of memory. How can I successfully generate mini batch data for training.